# How to copy a file from local to server path in php using COPY command

Tags: php

How to copy local file from my xampp directory to server path. I have tried this code. I am still wondering Do I need ftp user name and password for this?

```
<?php
$remote_file_url = 'http://HOST_NAME/folder1/folder2/';
$local_file = '05fad57.jpg';
$copy = copy( $local_file,$remote_file_url);
?>
```

Any help would be greate

Comment: You cannot copy files from one server to another. php `copy` only works for files on same server. So either upload the files using ftp... or create a file on server to upload the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy a file from one location to another using HTTP. One possibility is to use FTP as you already stated, but this does depend on the capabilities of the remote server.

Comment: could you please provide me any example link. if possible. thnx

Answer (score 0):

File must in ZIP format then you can do this using `copy()`

```
/* Source File URL */
$remote_file_url = 'http://server-url/files.zip';  
 
/* New file name and path for this file */
$local_file = 'files.zip';  
 
/* Copy the file from source url to server */ 
$copy = copy( $remote_file_url, $local_file );  
 
/* Add notice for success/failure */
if( !$copy ) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
else{
    echo " success to copy $file...\n";
}
```

[Good tutorial check here](https://shellcreeper.com/move-files-server-to-server-using-simple-php/)